# py2exe: building executable hangs

Tags: python, windows, anaconda, py2exe

I'm currently trying to use `py2exe` to compile a large project into a Windows executable for easy redistribution.  Before tackling this large project, I wanted to make some first steps.  This is my `test.py` script

```
print("Hello World!")
```

and this is my `setup.py`

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe

setup(console=['test.py'])
```

just as described in the [`py2exe` Tutorial](http://www.py2exe.org/index.cgi/Tutorial).

Now I enter in the command prompt (`cmd.exe`)

```
> python setup.py py2exe
running py2exe
```

and that's it.  It now *hangs* at `running py2exe` ([This](http://www.py2exe.org/index.cgi/Tutorial#Step3) is the expected output).  When I try to Ctrl-C out of it, I enter an infinite loop of

```
Traceback (most recent last call):
  File "_ctypes/callbacks.c", line 234, in 'calling callback function'
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\py2exe\dllfinder.py", line 92, in status_routine
    @_wapi.PIMAGEHELP_STATUS_ROUTINE
KeyboardInterrupt
```

where repeated Ctrl-C duplicates this error message.  I have to kill the `python.exe` process in `taskmgr` to quit.

---

My setup is

- Windows 7 Professional N 64-bit (Build 7601; Service Pack 1)
- [Anaconda Windows 64-bit Python](https://www.continuum.io/downloads)
- [PyPI `py2exe` 0.9.2.0](https://anaconda.org/pypi/py2exe) (installed with `pip install -i https://pypi.anaconda.org/pypi/simple py2exe`)

This is my first time developing software on Windows, so I have no idea how to debug or otherwise troubleshoot things.

---

Related questions:

- [Why does py2exe stop at “running”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37406228) (Very related, but no usable answer)

Comment: In my case, py2exe complains about `run-py3.5-win-amd64.exe` missing. this makes me wonder if 3.5 is actually supported. tested also anaconda 64bit python 3.5.1.   whl file that `pip` grabs is `py2exe-0.9.2.0-py33.py34-none-any.whl`. no py35 in there... Have you tried python 3.4?

Comment: I think 3.5 is not supported yet. check this commend: http://stackoverflow.com/a/36508064/566035